# Why pytest (pytest-django) doesn't have access to .env variables through decouple which regular django files access as normal?

Tags: django, environment-variables, pytest, pytest-django, python-decouple

I have a `django` project and I'm setting up my testing environment with `pytest` and `pytest-django`.

Previously, I have set up my environment variables like `DB_HOST` using `decouple` module. These variables work fine when they are used by regular `django` Python files.

However, when I run `pytest` on tests which use the same files, these variables are not found.

`decouple.UndefinedValueError: DB_HOST not found. Declare it as envvar or define a default value.`

My `pytest.ini` file:

```
[pytest]
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = bapi_django.settings
```

The error suggests to declare these variables, but it seems anti-DRY to me.

Is there anyway I can use my `django` project level `env` variables or do I have to redefine them from scratch?

Answer (score 0):

Do you set the `DB_HOST` in your `settings.py`?

I have not used `decouple`, instead I am using a `.env`-file with the `environ` module and have the following in my `settings.py`:

```
import environ

env = environ.Env(DEBUG=(bool, False))

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

# Take environment variables from .env file
environ.Env.read_env(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ".env"))
```

Looking through the decouple readme something like this should work in your `settings.py`:

```
from decouple import config

DB_HOST = config("DB_HOST")
```